# Updating SWT objects from another thread

Tags: java, swt

In my Java application, when the main module is invoked, i start my SWT GUI in a separate thread. I need to perform some long opertations in the main thread and update the GUI thread. When I try to update the GUI thread from the main thread i.e. change a label text or something, i get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. From what I've read online is because SWT doesn't allow non-UI threads to update UI objects. How can I update the GUI thread from the main thread.

I've found some examples online but they all deal with the scenario in which the GUI runs in the main thread and long operation is in separate thread. My scenario is the total opposite.

Could someone tell me how I can update widgets in the GUI thread?

Comment: Generally you do not get a `NullPointerException` when you update some GUI component from the wrong thread. Are you really sure that's a threading issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` because you are trying to access the GUI component before it is created. Ideally you should wait for the gui component to get created... for example...

I create a single GUI in a separate thread... like this

```
package test;


import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class GUIThread implements Runnable 
{
    private Display display;
    private Label label;
    public Display getDisplay(){
        return display;
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,false));
        label = new Label(shell,SWT.NONE);
        label.setText(" -- ");
        shell.open();
        shell.pack();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public synchronized void update(final int value)
    {
        if (display == null || display.isDisposed()) 
            return;
        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                label.setText(""+value);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

And in my main method i do something like this....

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final GUIThread gui = new GUIThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(gui);
        t.start();

        Thread.sleep(3000); // POINT OF FOCUS
        Display d = gui.getDisplay();

        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        {           
            System.out.println(i + "  " + d);
            gui.update(i);  
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if we comment out the `POINT OF FOCUS` in the above code then I will always get `NullPointerException`... But a delay of 3 seconds gives my GUI thread enough time to be in ready state and hence it doesn't through `NullPointerException`.....

In scenario like this you have to efficiently use the `wait` and `yield` methods... otherwise it would result in "Hard to find Bugs"... i.e. wait for UI to properly instantiate and then yield...

Also the actual processing is done in main thread and GUI is running in separate thread... to communicate properly it is good to have some shared and synchronized data structure... or it could be done using socket communication... your main thread populating some `port` and your GUI thread `asynchronously` listening on that port....

Hope this will through some light on your problem....

Comment: Hi Favonius. The `NullPointerException` was caused by exactly what you said. You answer helped me fixed both troubles — updating the GUI and get rid of that error. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

To say things short, SWT is a single-threaded UI toolkit. As a consequence, widgets must be updated in SWT event thread, like in Swing. Thus, you'll have to call the refresh using anonymous `Runnable` classes :

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        someSwtLabel.setText("Complete!");
    }
});
```

For a longer explanation, this [JavaLobby](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t43753.html) article is a good introduction to this threading usage model.

Comment: you can also use the syncExec to get a synchronous update if you need it. But I also join the others, saying your problem is different - you're accessing a null reference. You'll get a different exception when trying to invoke some SWT method in a non-ui thread (Invalid thread access or something like this)

Comment: Any tricks, if you want to update the UI using JNI Invocation API calling methods in an native thread? All I get is a locked up UI even if the backing thread does not call any java methods. If I try (a)syncExec the effect stays the same. A Locking UI...